# How to filter records with RESTful models and controllers in Yii2

Tags: php, rest, yii, yii2

I'm creating a RESTful API with Yii2 and have successfully setup a model named Contacts by following the Quick Start Tutorial*. I love how records can be created, listed, updated and deleted without creating any actions.

However I can't see how to filter results. I would like to only return contacts where contact.user_id is equal to 1 (for example) as it currently will reply with all records. Is this possible without creating the actions?

I am unsure also how I can limit results. From what I've read I feel it should append the URI with ?limit=5.

- http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-rest-quick-start.html

Comment: I think you should override index action

Comment: I'm trying to avoid that. I found in Yii1 there was a beforeFind() method that I think would do what I'm after but can't find how to do the same in Yii2.

Comment: I think the data provider can take values like when they filter in grids.check the url of page when filtering the grid

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should return a dataprovider instead of a set of objects, that supports pagination for you. 
Perhaps this approach will be a bit more useful:

```
public function actionIndex() 
{
   return new \yii\data\ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => Contact::find()->where(['user_id' => \Yii::$app->user-id]),
   ]);
}
```

You could also leave the index action intact, but provide the preset action with a `prepareDataProvider`-callback:

```
public function actions()
{
    $actions = parent::actions();
    $actions['index']['prepareDataProvider'] = function($action) 
    {
        return new \yii\data\ActiveDataProvider([
           'query' => Contact::find()->where(['user_id' => \Yii::$app->user-id]),
        ]);
    };

    return $actions;
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I was after.  Edit: Your second option is the result I am referring to.

Comment: I concur, the second solution is as clean as it gets. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have had to override the index method despite not wanting to. My solution looks like this:

```
public function actions()
{
    $actions = parent::actions();
    unset($actions['index']);

    return $actions;
}

public function actionIndex()
{
    return Contact::findAll(['user_id' => \Yii::$app()->user-id]);
}
```

I guess this solution means I need to write my own pagination code however which is something else I was hoping to avoid.